# Doubt with the heat capacities

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, volume

We know we can write the internal energy as:

$$dU=\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}dT+\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}dV=C_v dT+\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}dV$$ and things started to not make sense, is it that legal to use $C_v$ in an expression where you don't necessarily assume that V is constant and therefore you can't cancel out the $dV$, but **at the same time** you are using $C_v$ in your expression, which **at the same time** assumes volume to be constant? This isn't the first time I have seen this, I have always seen a lot of equations that had $C_v$ or $C_p$ as well as the differentials of pressure and volume and at all times, not the $dV$ nor the $dP$ cancelled, why is that?

Comment: In the “**constant-pressure** heat capacity” and “**constant-volume** heat capacity,” the bolded terms are part of the **name** of a parameter, not constraints on its use (given that the correct definition is used, of course). I always found it interesting that nobody ever has a problem with the **constant-temperature** bulk modulus or the **constant-pressure** thermal expansion coefficient, for example. Probably because those parts of the names are dropped without fear of ambiguity. (The **constant-entropy** bulk modulus is much less commonly used, for example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to use the isochoric specific heat in an expression which doesn't hold volume constant, just like its fine to use $(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_T$ in this same expression even though the other variable, $T$, isn't held constant.

The multivariable chain rule tells you that for a function of 2 variables (or more) $f(x,y)$, the change $\mathrm d f$ is equal to the change due to one variable changing while the other stays the same, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm dx$, plus the change due to the other variable changing while the first stays constant, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm dy$.

$$\mathrm df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm dy$$

Again, the existence of a partial derivative of a given variable in an expression doesn't imply all other variables in every term of the expression must be held constant, its just expressing the sole contribution of a given variable to the total change of the function.

If we want to express a change in internal energy in terms of a change of $T$ and $P$ then the equation is just like you stated
$$\mathrm dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\mathrm dT + \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\mathrm dV$$
Now these partial derivatives are expressions of how internal energy changes exclusively due to a temperature change, and how internal energy changes exclusively due to a volume change, respectively. The best way to find their values is to hold one variable constant and see what comes out.

We additionally know from the first law of thermodynamics $\mathrm d U = \delta Q - \delta W$ that that the change in internal energy is equal to the heat added minus the work done by the system. If volume is held constant then we have both $\mathrm d V = 0$ and $\delta W = 0$ so $\delta Q = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\mathrm dT$, so the rate of change of internal energy with respect to temperature at constant volume is just the rate of heating with respect to temperature change at constant volume, i.e. the isochoric specific heat:
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} = \left(\frac{\delta Q}{\mathrm d T}\right)\bigg|_V = C_v$$

So what this means is that the contribution to the change in internal energy due to a change in temperature while volume is held constant is equal to the heat added to the system due to a change in temperature while volume is held constant. This doesn't mean that volume has to be held constant in your specific process, its just telling you how much temperature alone contributes to the change during the process.

$$\mathrm d U = C_V\mathrm d T +\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\mathrm d V$$